# What is `stty line NUMBER` even doing?

Tags: tty, stty

According to [this](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) page, this field describes the "line discipline", which determines what happens when a user presses backspace or ^C. Essentially, what happens when a program calls `read(2)`.

However, setting it seems to have no effect. On my Linux machine, I have two line disciplines:

```
$ cat /proc/tty/ldiscs
n_tty       0
n_null     27
```

but `$ stty line 27` doesn't seems to affect anything. Backspace still works as normal.

If I do `$ stty -icanon`, however, I do see a change---backspace no longer works normally, and programs read things character by character (`read(2)` seems to always return just 1 character).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

Line disciplines are a layer between the tty driver and the tty core (see this picture, from [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch18.html)):
[image]

If you set it to 27 (tty_null) your date goes through the left side of the diagram (skipping the line discipline). If you set it to 0 then it goes through the default line discipline, that can handle both raw input, and *cooked* input.

```
TTY(0)
    The default line discipline, providing transparent operation (raw mode)
    as well as the habitual terminal line editing capabilities (cooked mode).
```

A list of other disciplines is [here](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-ldattach/).

You can write your own, or use one an existing one. I you have the `slip` module and you insert it `modprobe slip`, you will notice this:

```
$ cat /proc/tty/ldiscs 
n_tty       0
slip        1
n_null     27
```

When you did `$ stty line 27` you removed the line discipline (you set it to the null line discipline), when you did `$ stty -icanon` you set the default line discipline, in raw mode.

Comment: Right so what will be different when I set the ldisc to 27? How can I notice the difference?

Comment: The difference between no filter at all and a passthrough filter (raw mode) is just the number of layers the data traverses. I you sent huge amounts of data, you could expect more resources to be used. Anyway, the things I think you want to notice are all set at the tty core level (icanon, brk, ...), on top of the tty discipline. If you see the [source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/n_tty.c) for the default line discipline you will find how icanon or echo are read and used.

Answer (score 3):

`stty line N` is not doing much of anything.

To change the line discipline on Linux, it should call [`ioctl(TIOCSETD)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html), but it's not doing that; `stty line N` is just changing the (non-standard) `c_line` field of the termios struct, and then calling `tcsetattr(3)` -> `ioctl(TCSETS*)`, which will simply change the `c_line` field that will be returned by subsequent `tcgetattr(3)` -> `ioctl(TCGETS)` calls.

At the end of this answer is small C example program which should really change the line discipline on its stdin fd.

This is not the only way `stty(1)` is inadequate; `stty` is also not able to set "non-standard" baud rates (which could be easily done on Linux with the `TCSETS2`/`TCSETSW2`/`TCSETSF2` ioctls, but which unfortunately are not exposed in the standard C library, and are not used by `stty`).

```
$ cat > tiocsetd.c <<'EOT'
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(int ac, char **av){
        int o;
        if(ioctl(0, TIOCGETD, &o)) err(1, "io(TIOCGETD)");
        if(ac > 1){
                int n, d = atoi(av[1]);
                if(ioctl(0, TIOCSETD, &d)) err(1, "io(TIOCSETD)");
                if(ioctl(0, TIOCGETD, &n)) err(1, "io(TIOCGETD)");
                printf("%d -> %d => %d\n", o, d, n);
        }else
                printf("%d\n", o);
        return 0;
}
EOT
$ cc -Wall tiocsetd.c -o tiocsetd
$ ./tiocsetd
0

$ tty
/dev/pts/4 ## << make a note of this
$ cat /proc/tty/ldiscs
n_tty       0
n_null     27
$ ./tiocsetd 27
<your tty is hugged ;-)>
```

To restore it, run `./tiocsetd 0 </dev/pts/4` from another terminal (replace `/dev/pts/4` with the actual tty), then press `^C`.

Comment: Wait so it just changes the value returned when querying the ldisc? It doesn't otherwise change the tty's line processing?

Comment: Trying this just killed my bash process.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No, it did not.

Comment: btw, "querying the ldisc" is done with `TIOCGETD` as already shown in my example.